# How to create Single instance through CoCreateInstance?

Tags: visual-c++, com, createinstance

As I understood IClassFactory::CreateInstance creates a single instance of the COM object.  But is there a way I can use the CoCreateInstance to create single instance similar to IClassFactory::CreateInstance. Every time CoCreateInstance  is called it should create the com object only if one doesn't exist already.

Comment: You have to build this into the object itself - the object's class factory should return an error if the object already exists. This could be implemented by a system-wide mutex

Comment: Looks like you misunderstand what IClassFactory does.  Singleton behavior must be enforced by the server.  While a custom IClassFactory implementation can do that, and if it does then CoCreateInstance() will behave the same way, it is best to hide the coclass and provide another one that has a simple interface with a factory function that returns the one-and-only instance.  Saves you from having to fight with a stock IClassFactory implementation and can make it a lot more intuitive to the client programmer.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant  for the reply.